# Maximal distance of a segment from $0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Pick two distinct vectors $a,b$, with $b\neq 0$, in a Banach space $X$ (not necessarily Hilbert), and define the function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbf{R}$ by
$$
\forall t \in [0,1], \quad 
f(t):=\|a+tb\|.
$$
Is it true that $f$ is maximized in $t=0$ or in $t=1$?

I know that $f$ is a continuous function defined on a compact set, hence a maximum exists, let us say in $t_0$. Where is the contradiction if $t_0 \in (0,1)$? I think that I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Of course the minimum distance *might* occur at an interior point, but the maximum distance can only be attained at an endpoint..

Comment: @hardmath The "only"-part is not exactly true, since segments of constant norm are possible in some spaces.

Comment: However, argmax is always one of the three: 1) one of the endpoints; 2) both the endpoints; 3) the entire segment.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: I phrased it poorly.  I meant "only" in the sense of necessity (that the max is attained at an endpoint), while it is *possible* for the min to occur at an interior point (or at an endpoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed balls in a normed space are convex. Since $\overline B(0,\max\{\lVert b+a\rVert,\lVert a\rVert\})$  contains both the endpoints of the segment, it must contain the entire segment. Therefore the answer is yes: one of the extremal points maximizes the norm. It is possible (see non-[strictly convex norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space)) that all the points in the segment do, though.